# Apache Ignite Query Failing

Tags: database, nodes, cluster-computing, ignite

My Ignite table has 3.5 million rows and counting.

If i am running a query to get all the rows or to get latest 100k rows it fails, and stop the execution of the node.

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName>;
SELECT * FROM <TableName> ORDER By ID DESC LIMIT 100000;
```

Whether as getting first 100k rows or for getting latest 100k works.

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName> ORDER By ID LIMIT 100000;
SELECT * FROM EVENTSDATA WHERE ID > (SELECT Max(ID) FROM EVENTSDATA - 100000) LIMIT 100000;
```

My Ignite config file:

```
<property name="memoryPolicies">
 <list>
  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.MemoryPolicyConfiguration">
    <!--<property name="name" value="2GB_Region_Eviction"/>-->
    <property name="initialSize" value="#{4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
    <property name="maxSize" value="#{12L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
    <!--<property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>-->
  </bean>
 </list>
</property>
  <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
              <property name="initialSize" value="#{1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
              <property name="maxSize" value="#{8L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}" />
              <!-- 50 GB. -->
              <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
           </bean>
        </property>
     </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="discoverySpi">
     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
            <property name="addresses">
              <list>
                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
              </list>
            </property>
           </bean>
        </property>
     </bean>
  </property>
```

[image]

We are following the first approach as in the image.

Can someone suggest me with the query optimisation or apache Ignite configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the node fails due to an out of memory exception or long GC pauses when Java Heap gets saturated. A primary  technique is increasing the heap size and tuning failureDetection timeout.

But before going that approach, I’m not sure if there is any real need for reading an entire table with SQL. If you need to traverse significant subset of the data then use compute tasks with scan queries or local SQL queries:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/collocated-computations

As for SQL tuning, check this page:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/sql-tuning

Answer (score 0):

Try the "lazy" mode for the query: SqlFieldsQuery#setLazy.
It works great for simple plain SELECT with simple filters (without aggregates and subqueries). In this case the engine iterates data instead of load all result set to heap.